# Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that your installed packages have unment dependences

Tags: error-handling

```
dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hostapd : Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, please?

Answer (score 0):

It will be `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` instead of `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

If any dependency is missing try `sudo apt-get --fix-missing install`

You can also try the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

To install initscripts try:

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run install initscripts
```

You can try removing broken packages by:

1. Open the `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` log file in a text editor.
2. Locate any "broken" packages and remove them with `sudo apt-get remove <package>`.

Note: in newer versions, the log is located in `/var/log/apt/term.log` instead.

Comment: dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
[sudo] password for dipendra: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hostapd : Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hostapd : Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: You are still trying `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` instead of `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`

Comment: dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hostapd : Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$

Comment: I can not install anything.dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hostapd : Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo dpkg -a --configure
dipendra@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~$ sudo apt-get --dry-run install initscripts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package initscripts is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  util-linux util-linux:i386 sysvinit-utils:i386 sysvinit-utils

E: Package 'initscripts' has no installation candidate

Comment: i have term.log file but its empty file without any codes or something.

Comment: root@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~# sudo apt-get remove term.log
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package term.log
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'term.log'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'term.log'
root@dipendra-Inspiron-3437:~#